# Can't install and add anything from Nodejs to npx, npm and yarn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I know this has been ask many times and I have tried everything from the solution given on the other post but unfortunately it doesn't work and I am wondering why. I could not figure out what could be the culprit.

Yesterday it was not a problem I was doing things as usual I could even

```
 yarn add <package>
```

Today I was dong my project which is a reactjs app and trying out some packages by doing yarn add and at some point it hangs up having this message

```
 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

so cancelled it and and add again and same thing happens, so I restarted my computer. Then I decided to just leave the project as is for now and move on to my next one. I was going to create a react native project this time with

```
 npm install -g react-native-cli
```

and it also hangs up until fetchMetadata (I went to eat dinner for about an hour and nothing happens, doesn't move one dot)

```
 [  ................] / fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule glob@7.1.6 checking installable 
 status
```

I can't start the react-native init because I can't install cli. Then I went to clone the project instead from github and just do an npm install but same error message shows. Even with yarn install. Both hangs up at Fetching packages...

```
 [2/4] Fetching packages...
 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...

 An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-native/-/react-native- 
 0.62.2.tgz: unexpected end of file".

 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in 
 "E:\\Download 2nd\\00 Developer Sites\\Github Repos\\katoto-web-rtc\\yarn-erro
 r.log".

 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

So I again decided to just reinstall Nodejs and clear all npm caches. I clicked all updates from nodejs to install chocolatey and phyton but same thing happens,

```
 python is not installed. Installing...
 Progress: Downloading python3 3.9.0... 15%
 python not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The operation has timed out.
```

and at the end of installation:

```
 Chocolatey upgraded 1/2 packages. 1 packages failed.

 Failures
  - python (exited 1) - python not installed. An error occurred during installation:
  The operation has timed out.
  Type ENTER to exit:
```

I restarted turned off antivirus, turned off firewall and everything, uninstalled nodejs again, this time I choose to install nodejs only. Restarted my computer, Restarted my router (I'm at home and the only one using the net), I also flush DNS to clear cache and went back to install react native again, still same error message appear.

And currently now I am testing to do create react app (because I cant install react native I am checking If reactjs will work) unfortunately even react js hangs up.

```
npx create-react-app sample
[##................] - fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule balanced-match@1.0.0 checking 
installable status
```

I feel much more useless today than any other day. I've been doing this the whole day and I don't know why every installation is not working. I already disabled everything, I don't know if reformating my PC will help but I can't do it right now it will take too much time. How do I solve this?

Comment: This looks like a firewall/network issue on your machine rather than a npm/yarn issue, have you tried another network ? Is there any firewall on the one you are using ?

Comment: I already disable everything firewall and anti virus, rebooted my router, flush dns. I haven't tried other network yet as I only have one at home. I don't really know what is causing this, Even yarn add doesn't work. But yesterday it was working I can install packages , it only happens today. Wonder why.

Comment: I called my isp provider early this morning I told them I'm having network problem and ask them if I could factory reset the main router with the cable tv connection, they guide me through the correct settings. after that I tried to reinstall everything and now it's working even if firewall and antivirus is on. I guess it was my router that is causing the problem.